# In Rogue One, why did the Deathstar not aim directly at its target?

Tags: star-wars, death-star, rogue-one

In Rogue One, towards the end the imperials...

> ...decide to fire the Deathstar on the base on Scarif. Their motivation seemed to be vengeance to the rebels that were fighting there, as well as protection to make sure they did not extract any vital information.

> But when they fire, they miss the base. Instead the Deathstar blast fires through the tower, and hitting the ground some distance (miles?) away.

Were they rushing and accidentally missed, or did they miss on purpose?